# Can't pipe Output of Hadoop Command

Tags: java, hadoop, ssh, pipe, dd

I want to run the following command:

```
 hadoop fs -copyToLocal FILE_IN_HDFS | ssh REMOTE_HOST "dd of=TARGET_FILE"
```

However, when I try, all it does, is create an empty file on the target host and copy it to my local home drive, instead of copying it to the remote location.

> $ hadoop fs -copyToLocal FILE_IN_HDFS | ssh REMOTE_HOST "dd of=test.jar"
>
> 0+0 Datensätze ein
>
> 0+0 Datensätze aus
>
> 0 Bytes (0 B) kopiert, 1,10011 s, 0,0 kB/s

I cannot think of any reason, why this command would behave in this way.
Is this some Java-ism that I'm missing here, or am I actually doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-copyToLocal` option expects 2 arguments: the file in HDFS, and the local path. I'm not even seeing how this can copy to your local drive, this command fails for me.

But I think the actual issue is different: the `-copyToLocal` option doesn't print anything on  stdout that can be piped to the `ssh` command. Here you're essentially piping an empty stream to `dd`, so there is nothing to create.

I would do the following command which seems to work:

```
hadoop fs -cat $FILE_IN_HDFS | ssh $REMOTE_HOST "dd of=$TARGET_FILE"
```

Like this you are piping a stream which is the content of your file and copying it to the file pointed to by `$TARGET_FILE`. Tested on my box and this works fine.

This avoids the need to copy the file locally and then scp'ing the file to the remote box, everything is streamed, which is I believe what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps: first copyToLocal, then scp. You will also need to remove the intermediate local file.

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal $FILE_IN_HDFS $LOCAL_FILE
scp $LOCAL_FILE $REMOTE_HOST:$TARGET_FILE && rm $LOCAL_FILE
```